# OPenRefine GREL removing words if present in another column

Tags: openrefine, grel

I have a big list of medication names and want to remove the words that are present in column 'delete'. I've tried multiple different methods and non have worked.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several approaches to solve this in OpenRefine.
For all of them I am assuming you are in a [transform](https://openrefine.org/docs/manual/cellediting#transform) dialog on the column where you want to remove the words. I am also assuming that you only want to remove one word, as shown in your example data.

**Option 1: [replace](https://openrefine.org/docs/manual/grelfunctions#replaces-s-or-p-find-s-replace)**

```js
value.replace(row.cells["delete"].value, "")
```

This approach does not work, if the words in delete may be **part** of a word.
For example "TAB" would also be replaced in "AMA**TAB**BON".
You might use regular expressions for that. But afaik [GREL](https://openrefine.org/docs/manual/grel) does not have a way to dynamically create regular expressions (yet).

**Option 2: [Jython](https://openrefine.org/docs/manual/jythonclojure#jython)**

```py
import re
regex = re.compile(r'\b'+re.escape(row.cells["delete"].value)+r'\b')
return regex.sub("", value)
```

**Option 3: [filter](https://openrefine.org/docs/manual/grel#filtere1-v-e-test)**

```js
filter(value.split(" "), v, v != row.cells["delete"].value).join(" ")
```

This expression will split the words on the separator whitespace " ", remove words that are in the corresponding row in column delete and then join the remaining words back together on whitespace " ". You may also expand this to consider multiple words in columns delete:

```js
with(
  row.cells["delete"].value.split(" "),
  forbiddenWords,
  filter(value.split(" "), v, not(forbiddenWords.inArray(v))).join(" ")
)
```